# My "From spreadsheet - On form submit" trigger is getting disabled every time I try to run it - how do I find out why?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-forms

I have a Google form that collects reddit usernames in a Google sheet. I have a script to check whether the username doesn't exist (i.e. `https://www.reddit.com/user/<username>` gives a 404) or is banned (username looked up against a list `var banned_users = [...]`). If it is non-existent or banned, I mark the row orange. Here's the script:

```
function validateUser() {
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet_id);
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
   var last_row_number = sheet.getLastRow();
   var reddit_username = sheet.getRange(last_row_number, 2).getValue();
   var reddit_username_cell = sheet.getRange(last_row_number, 2);
   var reddit_username_row = sheet.getRange(last_row_number, 1, 1, 19);

   if (banned_users.indexOf(reddit_username) != -1) {
    reddit_username_cell.setNote('This user is banned.');
    reddit_username_row.setBackground('#ff9900')
  } else {
     var url = 'https://www.reddit.com/user/' + reddit_username.slice(2) // Get rid of the leading 'u/'
     var options = {
        'muteHttpExceptions': true,
        'followRedirects': true
     };
     var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
     var http_code = response.getResponseCode();

     if (http_code == '404') {
       reddit_username_cell.setNote('This user does not exist.');
       reddit_username_row.setBackground('#ff9900') // #ff9900 is default orange
    }
  }
}
```

This script works when I manually run the function. It successfully marks banned or non-existent users when I make a form submission and trigger it from the script editor. However when I add a trigger to run it on form submit, and then make a form submission, it gets disabled:

[image: Trigger Disabled]
[image: Unknown Reason]

I don't understand why. There is no email explaining the reason or logs showing that it ran at all. **How do I find out why this trigger is getting disabled and how do I fix it?** Thank you!

Comment: How long has this been occuring?

Comment: I just noticed that your using `setActiveSheet` perhaps you're getting an error there because when you run from a trigger there is no user and therefore no user interface.  I don't recall the exact terminology but it's something like `this method is not available in this environment` but that's just a guess.

Comment: Hey @Sidewinder were you able to solve your issue with my answer? Please consider [upvoting/accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it in case it was useful to you. Otherwise, kindly describe the issue you are having,  so we may help you. Cheers

Comment: @Cooper my bad for not acknowledging sooner, I was super swamped. This only started happening when I made this post, I had deleted my project's triggers and was setting them up afresh. carlesgg97's answer did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running it from a standalone script (not Sheets-bound) I get the following error:

> Please select an active spreadsheet first. (line 11, file "Code")

upon executing the line:

```js
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
```

Triggers do run scripts in a standalone fashion too, so I suggest you avoid using `active` sheets. Instead, you can simply replace above line of code for the following:

```js
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response - this worked. I think this was a holdover from when 
I was using the function when the sheet was open in front of me. When I switched it to standalone, I should have removed references to `active`. Your answer helped me catch a couple of other instances of this as well. Marking as accepted, thank you so much.